# Toggle boolean value in Firestore with React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, desktop-application

I'm currently building a TODO app with React and Firestore.
It's my first time using firestore, and I have run into an issue.

I have created functions for adding and removing todos from the database and UI.
However I ran into some difficulties when trying to toggle the boolean value "completed".
This is my current function which is called onClick for the todo items.

```
const todos = firebase.firestore().collection("todos");

markComplete = (id) => {
  todos
   .doc(id)
   .update({ completed: !completed })
   .then(function () {
     console.log("Todo successfully updated!");
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // The document probably doesn't exist.
    console.error("Error updating todo: ", error);
  });
```

It seems I can't toggle the boolean value in this manner as the "!completed" returns undefined.

Any suggestions to how I'm supposed to toggle boolean values with React + Firestore?
I tried reading the documentation without success.

Comment: Note: 
I also tried assigning the value of currentComplete by running a .get() function, which would let me toggle the value like so: update{complete:!currentComplete}

This did not work for me due to response-times from the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first **read** the document in order to get the value of the `completed` field and, then, **write** back the new value.

```
  markComplete = (id) => {
    todos
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          return doc.ref.update({ completed: !doc.data().completed });
        } else {
          // Throw an error
        }
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log('Todo successfully updated!');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // The document probably doesn't exist.
        console.error('Error updating todo: ', error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Good to know I can get() and update in the same line!

Comment: We are actually [chaining the promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining), in order to execute the two asynchronous operations (`get()` and `update()`) back to back.